# Is there a way to print an AttributedString in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, subscript

I have an `AttributedString` with regular text and some subscripts. I would like to put the text in a `JLabel` without losing formatting.

Is this possible? And if not, what would be the best alternative?

EDIT: Here is some example code to further explain my question:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
public class LabelExample extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
  private JLabel label;
  private AttributedString as;
  public LabelExample()
  {
    as = new AttributedString("Ten to the fifth is 105");
    as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 22, 23);
    label = new JLabel(as);
    //the above line doesn't accept AttributedString 
    //as a suitable constructor
    this.add(label);
  }
  public void run()
  {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    LabelExample e = new LabelExample();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the example?

Comment: The best alternative would be to wrap the text in HTML tags.  Also, I'd suggest that it's not possible, as `JLabel` does not know anything about `AttributedString`

Comment: I've never worked with HTML in java. Could you give me a little example? I tried simply making the JLabel text:


    `label = new JLabel("Ten to the fifth is 10<sup>5</sup>.");`

Doing that just printed the literal string with no formatting.

Comment: Never mind, I forgot the `<html>`

Answer (score 0):

By overwriting the `JLabel` so it acts like a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and use its `paint` method. That is obviously not a good idea, just use a `JPanel` directly. A `Graphics2D` context knows how to deal with an `AttributedString` (the character iterator, to be specific).

`JLabel` knows about HTML rendering directly, maybe this helps you with your specific task as you can easily build an HTML string with superscript tags. I don't know of a comfortable way to convert an `AttributedString` to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use my AttributedLabel class.

```
public class AttributedLabel extends JLabel {

    AttributedString str;

    public AttributedLabel(AttributedString s){
        super(s);
        str = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        // Render the string
        g.drawString(as.getIterator(), 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `super(s)` is invalid as JLabel does not accept AttributedString to its constructor but this is close to the right way to do it.